# RandomForest() to return probabilities of positive result as well as classification

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm building a Random Forrest Classifier and I would like to return classification and associated probabilities. My result variable is either `1` or `0`, 1 being the positive class that I want to track.

```
no_of_trees <- 50
rf.under <- randomForest(as.factor(result) ~ . ,
                         data=data_balanced_under,
                         importance=TRUE,
                         ntree=no_of_trees) 

prediction <- predict(rf.under, df.test)
probability <- predict(rf.under, df.test, type="prob")
submit <- data.frame( predicted = prediction, actual = df.test$result)
```

I wanted probability to return the probability of positive results, however I get:

```
> probability
           0    1
242339  1.00 0.00
3356431 1.00 0.00
138327  1.00 0.00
111327  1.00 0.00
3307151 1.00 0.00
222414  1.00 0.00
1817297 1.00 0.00
3860922 1.00 0.00
1710532 1.00 0.00
```

in my output. What are these numbers on the left? I'm not sure what they are? I thought they are row numbers, but then, why aren't they indexed from 1,2,3..?
I tied to get `probability[,2]` which I'm assuming gives me probability of the result, but also doesn't work.

Ideally, I would like to include the probabilities in the `submit` data frame, but currently unable to do so.

Also, confusion matrix gives me:

```
confusionMatrix(data = submit$predicted, reference = df.test$result , positive="1")

#Reference
Prediction      0      1
         0 913730    160
         1  50872   8219
```

Is it possible to switch this around? So that it shows positive class "1" first?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your data as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`probability` returns the probability by class (here you have two classes so two columns).
This as been built this way to alow multiclass classification.

If you want probability of `result == 1` just take the second column of `probability`

Since you have highly unbalanced classes (0.8% of ones) your classifier tends to predict that it is always 0... So your probability of `result==1` is close to 0 for most exemples. This is why your probabilities doesn't look like probabilities.

Regarding the index of `probability`, it is `rownames(df.test)` the index of `df.test`. I guess you randomly splitted  `df.test` from `df`. So index doesn't start by 1.